# Showing that a solution of ODE that solves forwards in time solves backwards in time

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $x(t)$ satisfy the differential equation $\dot{x}=\frac{dx}{dt}=f(x(t))$ on an interval $[0,\tau]$.

Then how can I use this to show that $x$ also solves the same differential equation on $[-\tau,0]$?

My attempt is to consider $x(-t)$ and show that this is the solution to $\dot{x}=-f(x)$ then it satisfies $\dot{x}=f(x(t))$ on $[-\tau,0]$, but I haven't been able to nail this down. I would greatly appreciate some help.

Comment: There is no reason why the dynamics at negative time has to be the same as the dynamics at positive time.

Comment: @user10354138 If $x(t)$ satisfies $\dot{x}=f(x(t))$ then wouldn't $x(-t)$ satisfy $\dot{x}=-f(x(-t))$?

Comment: No.  You only know $x(t)$ for $t\in[0,\tau]$ satisfies $\dot{x}=f(x(t))$.  You can choose whatever you like for $x(t)$, $t\in[-\tau,0]$ (subject to only continuity/differentiability constraint at $0$) including for example solving a different DE $\dot{x}=g(x(t))$.  For example, $x(t)=e^t$ for $t\geq 0$ and $x(t)=1+t$ for $t<0$ solves $\dot{x}=x$ on $[0,\tau]$ but not $[-\tau,0]$.

Comment: @user10354138 Ok so does this make sense? Let $x(0)=x_0$. Then $x(t)=x_0+\int_0^t f(x(s))ds$ is the solution to $dx/dt = f(x)$. now take $y(t)=x_0-\int_{-t}^0 f(y(s))ds$ instead. Then taking derivative w.r.t $t$ we get $dy/dt = -f(y(-t))$. So we don't have $x(-t)=y(t)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autonomous ODE are invariant under shifts in time, if $x$ is a solution on some interval $[a,b]$, then $x_c(t)=x(t-c)$ is a solution on the interval $[a+c,b+c]$. This can be verified by simply inserting into the ODE
$$
\dot x_c(t)=\frac{d}{dt}x(t-c)=\dot x(t-c)=f(x(t-c))=f(x_c(t)).
$$
There is no reflection involved in the statement in question, and also no claim that the solution on $[-\tau,0]$ is a continuation of the solution on $[0,\tau]$.

Comment: Thanks I think this is what the notes that I got the question from meant.